# JavaScript not loading after partial update in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a problem with Javascript not load in asp.net when an updatepanel postback to the server and the problem is that javascript code is not in the same page where the updatepanel is so I can put it in pageLoad() function it is like this:

```
<script src="js/keyboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and i use ASP.Net 4 and c# and this is my code code:

```
<link href="css/keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: left; padding-right: 140px">
            <dx:aspxcombobox id="comboBoxLangauge" clientinstancename="comboboxLang"
                cssclass="combo" runat="server" width="140px" clientidmode="Static">
                <Items>
                    <dx:ListEditItem Text="English to Kurdish" Value="1" Selected="true" />
                    <dx:ListEditItem Text="Kurdish to English" Value="2" />
                </Items>
                <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="IndexChanged" />            
            </dx:aspxcombobox>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnTranslate" runat="server" Text="Search" ClientIDMode="Static"
            CssClass="Search" OnClick="btnTranslate_Click" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxWord" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
            class="keyboardInput Search" Style="width: 260px; direction: ltr"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autocom" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CompletionSetCount="10"
            EnableCaching="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1" TargetControlID="txtBoxWord" ServicePath="~/translator/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList">
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

        <asp:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="OutPanel"
            Corners="All" Radius="5" BorderColor="Silver">
        </asp:RoundedCornersExtender>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="OutPanel" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="width: 440px; height: 200px; overflow: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 10px;" visible="false">
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div id="OutPanel" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="width:440px;height:200px;overflow:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding-top:10px;" visible="false">

</div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"The problem is that javascript code is not in the same page where the updatepanel is"*

Whereas make sure your *JavaScript* is available on the page with `UpdatePanel` to load it properly.